# Is there a relation between the words "import" (trade) and "important" (valuable)?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Is there a relation between the words *import* (in a trade sense) and *important* (special, etc)? It seems to me that there is, or rather that there should be, but I was wondering if anyone can give some proper clarification.

Comment: *Important* means *of import*. But I suppose you're asking about *import* as an antonym of export. I'd make it clear in your question if I were you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The etymology of the two terms shows that they have the same origin, the Latin 'importare' (bring in):

Import (v.):

> - **early 15c., "convey information, express, make known, signify," from Latin importare "bring in, convey,"** from assimilated form of in- "into, in" (see in- (2)) + portare "to carry" (see port (n.1)). *Sense of "bring in goods from abroad" first recorded c.1500.*

Important(adj.):

> - mid-15c., from Middle French important and directly from Medieval Latin importantem (nominative importans), present participle of importare "be significant in," **from Latin importare "bring in" (see import)**.